# Bulild string variable that is actually an hexadecimal number

Tags: c++, string, hex

Say I have `string` variable:

```
string str1 = "\x11";
```

Say I want to build this `string` manually, meaning, I have:

```
string str2 = "11"
```

and would like to **naively** do:

```
string str3 = '\x' + "11"
```

Is there a way to construct `str3` in such way that `str3 == str1`?

Comment: str3 is always equal to str3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes like this:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << (char) 0x11;
std::string str3 = ss.str();
```

With:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
```

Or if you actually start with the "11" string:

```
std::string value = "11";
std::stringstream temp;
temp << std::hex << value;
char c;
temp >> c;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << c;
```

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux it works fine. I'd be happy if you could say in a couple of words why the first approach works.

Comment: Well, the 0x11 is just a compile time constant integer. You cast that to a char append that char to the stringstream.

Answer (score 0):

If you start out with an integer below 256 then you can just do

```
int small = 17; // 0x11 hex
sanity check here
str[0] = (char)small;
```

if you start out with a string

```
int small = HexToInt("11"); // 0x11 hex, find a HexToInt on the next.
sanity check here
str[0] = (char)small;
```